# How to use sendEmail to send an email to a list in a column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mailmerge

I have a list of emails in Column E that I need to send an email to. I have a bit of the code, and I'm just missing part of it I think. I also have different email lists in Columns B, H and K, but I only want to send an email to the list that's in Column E.

```
function Email() {
     var Sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Emails")
     var Range = Sheet2.getRange("E3:E");
     var Data = Range.getValues();
     var d = 0;
     for (var i = 0; i-d <Data.length; i++) {
       if(!Data[i-d][0]) 
       var Row = Data[i];
       var EmailAddresses = Row[0];
       var Subject = "CA01 - HOT Material Arrived: PO " + PurchaseOrder + " for " + HM_number + " " + HM_Description;
       MailApp.sendEmail(EmailAddresses, Subject, Message); // Sends email to the addresses on Email tab
       d++;
     }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this sample code:

```
function Email() {
     var Sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Emails")
     var Range = Sheet2.getRange("E3:E");

     //Use flat() to convert 2-d array to 1-d array
     var Data = Range.getValues().flat();

     //filter the non-empty cells using filter(String) and get its length
     var count = Data.filter(String).length;
     Logger.log(count);
     Logger.log(Data);

     //loop only non-empty cells with email addresses and send an email
     for(var i = 0; i<count; ++i){
       var email = Data[i];
       var subject = "test subject"
       var message = "HelloWorld!"
       MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,message);
     }
}
```

### What it does?

1. Get the range of Column E (from E3:E).
2. Get the values of the selected range. Use [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to convert 2-d array to 1-d array values.
3. Get the total number of non-empty cells in the array values by filtering the array using [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) then get its length.
4. Send email using [MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String)) for each email addresses based on the non-empty cell count